# no popup menu with "right-click" on layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, mac, arcgis-10.4

I am trying to work with ArcGIS 10.4 on a MacBook Pro (OS X El Capitan 10.11.5) using Microsoft Windows via Parallels Desktop 11.

"Right-click" in this context normally = "control-click." No matter what combination I use, however, I can't seem to get the popup menu that should appear. I've also tried to find work-arounds for commands in that menu, e.g., "export data...," but can't figure out any functional workaround.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve the menu problem or know of an "export data..." workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referencing [this article](http://kb.parallels.com/en/9151), I would try pressing Shift + Control and clicking with the mouse. The article had some other ideas too that involve some minor changes to your mac's system preferences. Much may depend on what type of mouse you are using.

For example if you are using an Apple magic/mighty mouse) you may need to set preferences to register a right click from the right side of the mouse.

If you are using the trackpad, you can set preferences ... Under system preferences, click on TrackPad and put a checkmark on Click or tap with two fingers for Secondary click. Then you can use 2 fingers on the trackpad to simulate a right-click.

Comment: You've solved the problem! Shift + Control + click (on trackpad) works. Thank you very much!

Comment: That's great. Can you please mark it as the accepted answer with the green check mark (and maybe give the answer an up-click)? :-)